# What are some cheaper versions of Multi Jet 3D printing?

Tags: desktop-printer

I noticed 3Dsystems has Multi Jet 3D printing where wax is used provide support and give users with high resolution 3D printed objects. I was wondering if there were cheaper and smaller Multi Jet 3D printing?

Can Form 1+ from FormLabs be considered to do the same job with resin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objet by Stratasys is a comparable technology (they call it PolyJet). SolidScape is also somewhat comparable (they also use jetting).

The FormLabs printers are not comparable. They use a completely different process, which can only print in one material. With jetting, you can mix different materials in the same part.